# @-webkit-keyframes does not work in play framework

Tags: animation, playframework

I want to use an animated refresh glyphicon in play framework :

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( "#update" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
    var $icon = $( this ).find( ".glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh" ),
      animateClass = "glyphicon-refresh-animate";

    $icon.addClass( animateClass );
    // setTimeout is to indicate some async operation
    window.setTimeout( function() {
      $icon.removeClass( animateClass );
    }, 2000 );
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
   -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "rotateThis" {
 from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg );
    }
 to  {
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 360deg );
    }
}
```

```html
<a id="update" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
```

but I receive this error: 
 Expected '}' but found '@'

Comment: You are missing **});** brackets in **js** part. So  add this brackets bottom of your script and also don't use **double quotes** in animation keyframes **name**  @Sebastian F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that there is an `@` symbol in `@-webkit-keyframes`. 
If this definition is inside of a Twirl template, then you will have 
problems.

To escape the symbol, use `@@`, which is described in this page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates

> Because @ is a special character, you’ll sometimes need to escape it. Do this by using @@

The better approach is not to have CSS in your template.

Comment: Thanks, I just wrote the CSS in a separated file :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this snippet will help you and also you can find where you are missing brackets and keyframes animation name too.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#update").on("click", function() {
    var $icon = $(this).find(".glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh"), animateClass = "glyphicon-refresh-animate";
    $icon.addClass(animateClass);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $icon.removeClass(animateClass);
    }, 2000);
   });
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
 -webkit-animation: rotateThis 2s linear infinite;
 animation: rotateThis 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateThis{
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotateThis{
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="container">
 <a id="update" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
</div>
```